# frequency table for banner list

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function to generate frequency table (to show count , valid percentage , percentage) for list of banner.

I want to export tables in xlsx files.
like for variable "gear" , i want to calculate the table for banner below ()

```
library(expss)
df <- mtcars

df$all<- 1
df$small<-ifelse(df$vs==1,1,NA)
df$large<-ifelse(df$am ==1,1,NA)

val_lab(df$all)<-c("Total"=1)
val_lab(df$small)<-c("Small"=1)
val_lab(df$large)<-c("Large"=1)

banner <- list(dat$all,dat$small,dat$large)

data <- df
var <- "gear"
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
expss::var_lab(data[[var]])        
#tab1 <- expss::fre(data[[var1]])
table1 <- expss::fre(data[[var1]],
                   stat_lab = getOption("expss.fre_stat_lab", c("Count N", "Valid percent", "Percent",
                                                                "Responses, %", "Cumulative responses, %")))
table1
```

the output table should be like below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make custom function around `fre`:

```
library(expss)
df <- mtcars

df$all<- 1
df$small<-ifelse(df$vs==1,1,NA)
df$large<-ifelse(df$am ==1,1,NA)

val_lab(df$all)<-c("Total"=1)
val_lab(df$small)<-c("Small"=1)
val_lab(df$large)<-c("Large"=1)

my_fre <- function(curr_var) setNames(expss::fre(curr_var)[, 1:3],
                                      c("row_labels", "Count N", "Valid percent"))

cross_fun_df(df, gear, list(all, small, large), fun = my_fre)

 # |        |   Total |               |   Small |               |   Large |               |
 # |        | Count N | Valid percent | Count N | Valid percent | Count N | Valid percent |
 # | ------ | ------- | ------------- | ------- | ------------- | ------- | ------------- |
 # |      3 |      15 |         46.88 |       3 |         21.43 |         |               |
 # |      4 |      12 |         37.50 |      10 |         71.43 |       8 |         61.54 |
 # |      5 |       5 |         15.62 |       1 |          7.14 |       5 |         38.46 |
 # | #Total |      32 |        100.00 |      14 |        100.00 |      13 |        100.00 |
 # |   <NA> |       0 |               |       0 |               |       0 |               |
```

Comment: what is cross_fun_df , getting error could not find function "cross_fun_df"

Comment: @coder2learn It seems, you need to update 'expss'

Comment: ok, Thanks , can you please also help in doing the same thing for multiple variables.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921539/function-to-create-percentage-tables-for-many-columns/70923625#70923625